# How to convert array to object for queryparams?

Tags: angular

I have this array['ca','ba','es']

How can i covnert to object so that i have `r=ca, r=ba, r=es.`

So in queryParams when i add i will have url something like this:

```
r=ca&r=ba&r=es
```

I tried something like this but its not working:

```
let obj = this.queries.r.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
      'r' = cur; 
      return acc;
    }, {});
```

Because r is not valid as param.Any suggestion how can i fix this?

Comment: ['ca','ba','es'].map(s => `r=${s}`).join("&")

Comment: this is not working...im getting error that can not find name r, $ ....

Comment: `['ca','ba','es'].map(s => \`r=${s}\`).join("&")`

Comment: and how can i assign this to queryParam  with rest of params? because right now i get [0]:r [1]:= [2]:c [3]:a . .... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think this should work in your case.

```
Const params = new HttpParams({fromObject: { r: yourArrayHere }}).
```

Make sure you import HttpParams from @angular.

Hope that helps!

Comment: im getting this: argument of type '{ fromObject: { r: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ fromString?: string; encoder?: HttpParameterCodec; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fromObject' does not exist in type '{ fromString?: string; encoder?: HttpParameterCodec; }'.
(property) OfferComponent.queries: any

Comment: Can you provide a line of example including your array?

Comment: let a = [];

    const params = new HttpParams({fromObject: { r: a}})

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? This functionality was added recently and might not be available if you are running old version. As per Angular code above example should work. See here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.0.9/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L122-L129

Comment: "@angular/cli": "1.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.6",

Comment: That’s the Angular CLI version. @angular version please?

Comment: "version": "4.3.1",

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an old version. Latest HttpParams fromObject won’t work.

Try something like this.

```
let params = new HttpParams()

['ca','ba','es'].forEach(item => {
     params = params.append(“r”, item);
}
```

Comment: and then what ? because then im getting array of objects and not object..

Comment: You can forEach over an array of objects same way I have shown. You get the object inside forEach callback function. You can access the value using whatever object key you want. This params variable then can be used with http.get and http.post.

Comment: HttpParams {updates: Array(2), cloneFrom: HttpParams, encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, map: null}
cloneFrom
:
HttpParams {updates: null, cloneFrom: null, encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, map: null}
encoder
:
HttpUrlEncodingCodec {}
map
:
null
updates
:
Array(2)
0
:
{param: "r", value: "ca", op: "a"}
1
:
{param: "r", value: "ba", op: "a"}
length
:
2

Comment: thats all i get when i console.log(params)

Comment: i want to do something like this Object.assign(obj, params) so in obj i will have r=ca & r=ba and so on

Comment: You can not have duplicate keys in the JS object. May I ask why you want to do something like that?